# "Unknown error" constantly, seems tied to user preferences

Tags: control-panel, server

I have a user group called Content Loaders with limited permissions. After creating a test user in this group I got an "An unknown error occurred" message every time I navigated anywhere in the CP or saved a change (though both were successful). I started adding back permissions and when I re-enabled *General > Perform Craft CMS and plugin updates*, the errors went away. Not sure if this is a configuration issue on this new staging server, but everything else seems to be working. I can't find any posts about similar issues. Obviously I don't want people doing data entry to be able to perform Craft updates! ;) Anyone have a clue what might be causing this?

Possibly related: even with an admin account checking for updates just shows the spinner image endlessly. I have no problem checking for updates on my local install. This is running on DigitalOcean (with ServerPilot), Ubuntu 14.04.4 x64 with PHP 7.

The only errors I saw in craft.log (which I cleared before doing something that caused the cpanel error to appear) looked like this:

`2016/07/31 03:45:43 [error] [php] include([snipped path]craft/plugins/commerce/vendor/composer/../guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Client.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory ([snipped path]craft/app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:412)`

Comment: This feels like one of three things... (1) a bug in Craft, (2) a corrupt or incomplete `app` folder, or (3) interference from a plugin. I'd start by replacing the entire `craft/app` folder with a fresh copy. If that doesn't work, which plugins are you currently using in your site?

Comment: +1 for @LindseyD's #2 guess. Sounds like a file (or multiple) didn't get uploaded/deployed correctly.

Comment: @LindseyD You're right! The `craft` folder transfer was incomplete but somehow the install still worked. I replaced the entire `craft/app` folder (unzipped Craft on the server and used `mv`) and updated the permissions. Same error. Also after disabling all plugins other than Commerce. But when I disabled Commerce I was able to check for updates again (already up to date), and under the limited user the errors no longer appear. Oddly, re-enabling plugins changes nothing. Seems okay now (no `[error]` in log), but do you think I should do a complete reinstall to be safe?

Comment: @ToddProuty Just re-uploaded the `app` folder should be good enough.  Would you mind adding your solution as an official answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was apparently caused by an *almost* complete but failed deployment of the `app` folder. Only a few files were missing/corrupted so Craft still worked other than the issue described.

I replaced the entire `craft/app` folder (deleted it, unzipped Craft on the server and used `mv`) and updated the permissions. At this point I got the same error. The error continued to show up after disabling all plugins other than Commerce. But when I disabled Commerce I was able to check for updates again (Craft was already up to date), and under the limited user the errors no longer appear. Oddly, re-enabling Commerce changes nothing. I did encounter a PHP error when navigating within Commerce, so I followed similar steps to upload a fresh copy. Everything appears to be working correctly now.